# Prove that $\{f_n\cdot g\}\rightarrow f\cdot g$ in measure.

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

From Royden's Analysis book (4th Edition) Chapter 5 Section 2 Problem 7:

> Let $E$ have finite measure, $\{f_n\}\rightarrow f$ in measure on $E$ and $g$ be a measurable function on $E$ that is finite a.e. on $E$. Prove that $\{f_n \cdot g\} \rightarrow f\cdot g$ in measure.

I've attempted many different approaches, but to no avail. If anyone could give a starting hint (not necessarily a solution), I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$f_n \rightarrow f$ in measure and $g$ be measurable and finite a.e. Prove that $f_ng \rightarrow fg$ in measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695284/f-n-rightarrow-f-in-measure-and-g-be-measurable-and-finite-a-e-prove-that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Idea:** Try looking at what happens when you restrict yourself to $A_k = \{ x : |g(x)| \in [0,k+1)\}$ for each $k\in \{0,1,\ldots\}$. What can you say about $\lim_k \mu(A_k^c)$ ?

*Note:* $A_k^c$ stands for the complement of $A_k$

Comment: So, correct me if I am wrong, but $\{A_k\}$ is an ascending sequence of measurable sets, ascending to $E$, so $\{A_k^c\}$ would then be a descending sequence of measurable sets. That must mean $\lim_k \mu(A_k^c)=0$, but even if this is correct, I don't see how this helps me with the proof.

Comment: @PitheMathemagician You forgot to say $\mu(A_1^c) \leq \mu(E) <\infty$, it is important that at least one of those sets have finite measure. Let $B_{n,\varepsilon} = \{x : |f_n(x)g(x)-f(x)g(x)|=|g(x)|\times | f_n(x)-f(x) | \geq \varepsilon\}$ we want to show the measure of this tends to $0$ as $n\to \infty$, with $\varepsilon$ fixed. The problem with these sets is that $|g(x)|$ over there, more specifically... when $|g(x)|$ can be made *too large*. But then, when you take $B_{n,\varepsilon}\cap A_k$, you know that $|g(x)| < k + 1$ there, and so $|f_n(x)-f(x)| \geq \frac{\varepsilon}{k+1}$...

Comment: Ok. That makes a lot of sense. Just for a bit more clarification, though, in your last sentence, are $k$ and $n$ the same integer or not?

Comment: @PitheMathemagician No, they are not. Can you see why we need them to be different? Try finishing the proof using these ideas.

Comment: Oh, is it because we need the $k$ to be fixed in order to apply the definition of convergence in measure to the set $B_{n,\epsilon}\cap A_k$?

Comment: That is exactly why! :)